# Can the sleep() function take floating point values?

Tags: raspbian, python, led

If I try to have my code sleep for an arbitrary non-integer value it appears that the sleep() function rounds to the nearest integer. For example:

```
GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
sleep(0.3)
GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
sleep(0.3)
```

Results in my LED blinking in 1 second increments. Does sleep() take floating point values?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a general programming question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

You have not told us which sleep() function you are using.

If you are using the one in the time module then it does support fractional times.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

> time.sleep(secs)
>
> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given
> number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to
> indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be
> less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the
> sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also,
> the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary
> amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

now = time.time()

for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(0.2)
   print(time.time()-now)
```

Results in

```
$ ./st.py
0.200302839279
0.400612831116
0.600860834122
0.801117897034
1.00143289566
1.20173883438
1.4020190239
1.6023080349
1.80258703232
2.00286793709
```